# Display city along with caller ID

Tags: android, phone, geo-location

On the iPhone the city is displayed if the phone number is not in your contact list.

Is there a way to do this same thing on the Android?

[image]

https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1322106&page=2

[City Caller ID says there is patent on this technology.](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20160528214859/http://www.threadabort.com/?p=24)

[This app may be a duplicate.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1543/is-it-possible-to-know-the-location-of-the-caller)

Comment: If you trust some [CallerID app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_callerid#group_84) (chose wisely, though I already kept some "obvious offenders" off that list I've not tested remaining candidates), some might include that. I'm not aware of any using some offline database, though – except for [City, Country, Caller ID](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.ipcas.callerCity) which was last updated ~4 years ago.

Comment: @Izzy Area codes for Mexico, Poland, Portugal, Sweden and Spain
  I should have posted I'm in the US.  I feel like this should have been built into Android just like the iPhone.

Comment: Agreed, William, but it obviously isn't. Some vendors might have included it, but AFAIK AOSP doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is an answer in progress but there was an app called ["City Caller ID"](https://web.archive.org/web/20150604233021/https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guidology.citystatecallerid) but it was pulled from the app store after being sued.  I have a copy of it backed up but it isn't complete.  A more current app that appears to work is [Phone 2 Location](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=and.p2) but it does cost money, but IMO it is worth every penny.  Also on Oreo it actually(in the US) displays the state on stock it appears now.  I need to confirm this on a Pixel because I am technically running Oreo on a Nexus device.